# How can I troubleshoot iCloud Drive for Windows?

Tags: icloud, windows

I'm having an issue with iCloud for Windows where the numbers of files it is uploading & downloading stays constant, i.e., they don't change for days. **I'm wondering if there is a standard way to troubleshoot this issue.** For example, is there some logging utility that I can use to see which files it is stuck on, or if there are specific errors that I can address?

[image: iCloud Drive in Taskbar]

I searched this forum and performed a general web search, but I couldn't find a reliable approach. Nor could I find anything on official Apple sites. Restarting the computer doesn't change anything.

FWIW, here are a few things I *have* discovered. They might not be relevant, but I found them interesting. Maybe you can tell me if they are related to my issue.

1. Sometimes when I delete or rename a file in File Explorer, the original comes right back. I can usually delete a file if I try again once or twice. If I performed a rename, I sometimes see the re-named file *and* the original, as if iCloud restored it.
2. If I use 7-Zip to compress a file along with the "Delete files after compression" option, the deleted file is immediately restored by iCloud Drive.

   - Deleting files using one the above approaches doesn't seem to affect the core problem, i.e., the number of files shown being uploaded or downloaded doesn't significantly change.
3. If I look at my iCloud Drive folders in File Explorer, I notice that several of the files with the "Sync Pending" status are from Apple apps, e.g., Numbers spreadsheets or Garage Band projects.

   [image: File Explorer showing Sync Pending files from Apple]
4. Some folders with "Sync Pending" have a twin folder that was *not* created by me. The name is identical, except it is appended with an underscore (_). The content of these folders are not necessarily identical, though. Some of the files inside are duplicated, but some are unique.

   [image: File Explorer showing twin Sync Pending folders]

FYI, I'm running Windows 10 Pro (21H2). The iCloud app is version 13.0.201.0.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the logs for my iCloud Drive instance in:

```
`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\AppleInc.iCloud_nzyjxcx40taaa\LocalCache\Local\Logs`
```

Now, nzyjxcx40taaa is specific to my installation, so look up for yours under Packages.